# Allocation isn't working properly

Tags: c

I'm trying to put values in an array by sending the pointer address to a function and create dynamic allocation in the function itself.
after the allocation, I get the first value in the first index.

This is the error message that for the problem:
Unhandled exception at 0x00941589 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.

This is what I have done:

```
void mamain()
{
    *A = NULL;
    func(&A);
}


void func(int** A)
{
  *A = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);

  *A[0] = 5;
  *A[1] = 8;
  *A[2] = 67;
  *A[3] = 2;
  *A[4] = 3;

   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   {
       printf("%d,", *A[i]);
   }
}
```

I don't understand why my code isn't working, trying to figure it out but no success.

Comment: Where is `A` declared?

Comment: In `mamain()`, where is `A` declared?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: did you define A as int * type -- looks to me like it should just be int * A

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` - that can mask more serious problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've assigned the result of your `malloc` call to `*A`, not `A`; thus, the *expression* `*A` is your array.  Since `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`, the expression `*A[0]` is parsed as `*(A[0])`; this isn't what you want.

You'll need to explicitly group the `*` operator with `A` before doing the subscript:

```
(*A)[0] = 5;
(*A)[1] = 8;
...
```